# Mysql query takes 1 second on localhost but 30 seconds on server

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have a problem with Mysql.

So I have the next query:

```
UPDATE jugador j 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 0) p1 ON j.Id = p1.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 1) p2 ON j.Id = p2.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 2) p3 ON j.Id = p3.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 3) p4 ON j.Id = p4.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 4) p5 ON j.Id = p5.FK_Jugador    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 5) p6 ON j.Id = p6.FK_Jugador    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 6) p7 ON j.Id = p7.FK_Jugador    
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 7) p8 ON j.Id = p8.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 8) p9 ON j.Id = p9.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, Puntuacion_Decimal AS Puntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 AND IndiceLast = 9) p10 ON j.Id = p10.FK_Jugador 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT FK_Jugador, SUM(Puntuacion) AS TotalPuntuacion FROM puntuacion WHERE Validado = 1 GROUP BY FK_Jugador) pt ON j.Id = pt.FK_Jugador 
    SET j.Puntuacion = pt.TotalPuntuacion, 
        j.U1 = p1.Puntuacion, 
        j.U2 = p2.Puntuacion, 
        j.U3 = p3.Puntuacion, 
        j.U4 = p4.Puntuacion, 
        j.U5 = p5.Puntuacion, 
        j.Jugando = FALSE, 
        j.Valor = POW((0.181818182*IFNULL(p1.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.163636364*IFNULL(p2.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.145454545*IFNULL(p3.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.127272727*IFNULL(p4.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.109090909*IFNULL(p5.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.090909091*IFNULL(p6.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.072727273*IFNULL(p7.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.054545455*IFNULL(p8.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.036363636*IFNULL(p9.Puntuacion, 3.5) + 0.018181818*IFNULL(p10.Puntuacion, 3.5)), 1.125) WHERE j.FK_Equipo = 1232
```

And the problem is that when I'm working on my localhost it works perfectly fine, it only takes 1 second, but when i upload it to my server it takes 30 seconds.

Does someone have any idea of why that happens and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

For the moment I had to change everything and work with a loop in PHP, but I'd like to fix it in Mysql..

Comment: If its readable, just maybe its debuggable

Comment: Presumably there's a bit more data on one of them. Now would be a good time to be asking yourself the question, should I really be joining a bazillion times to the same table? Might there be a better way?

Comment: And take account of network latency.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it using GROUP BY in every LEFT JOIN